# Fullcalendar Events lost color after Events Filtering

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have managed to put jquery filtering on the events of my calendar. But after after unfiltering, the events would lost the color I have defined to them. Any idea how to change that? THANK YOU!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'month',
                prev: 'left-double-arrow',
                next: 'right-double-arrow', 
                height: 650, 
                aspectRatio: 2,
                 eventSources: [
                    {   
                        googleCalendarApiKey: GAPI,
                        googleCalendarId: googleCalendarId1,
                        color: '#f25d1d',    
                        textColor: 'white' 
                    }
                ], // To prevent click access to G Calendar
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                },
                 header: {
                    left: '',
                    center:'prev title next',
                    right: 'month,listMonth,'
                }                     
            });

            $("#checkbox1").change(function() {
                if(this.checked) {
                  $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',  googleCalendarId1 );
                }
                else{
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource',  googleCalendarId1 );
                }
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question will not work at all - adding simply the calendar ID back in as the event source will cause fullCalendar to request that URL, and get a 404 back. The events from that google calendar will not be re-added to the calendar. This is aside from the issue you describe regarding colours.

Anyway, you are definitely losing the colour information as well. It is lost when you remove the event source, and when you add the event source back in (even if what you're doing would work) you don't re-provide that configuration info including the colour setting.

The obvious solution is to keep the event source config as a separate object in a variable, and then add and remove that variable each time. This will both keep the colour settings, and actually make the code above re-add the event source properly.

```
 var calendar1Source = {
    id: 1,
    googleCalendarApiKey: "SomeAPIKey",
    googleCalendarId: "SomeCalendarID",
    color: '#f25d1d',
    textColor: 'white'
  };

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventSources: [calendar1Source],
    // To prevent click access to G Calendar
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  });

  $("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', calendar1Source);
    } else {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', calendar1Source);
    }
  });
```

See this example for a working demo, using a public calendar I happen to know about: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/208/